# entities framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I Have the following code that I use.  However, I'm trying to use the Table Name to retrieve the data and the entities.

```
        SalesInvoiceList = (from p in entities.SalesCards
                            select new SalesInvoice
                            {
                                ID = p.ID,
                                InvoiceNo = p.InvoiceNo,
                                DateTime = p.DateTime,
                                ContactName = p.CustomerCard.ContactName,
                                CompanyName = p.CustomerCard.CompanyName
                            }).ToList();
```

I want to be able to do the following or something similar

```
        SalesInvoiceList = (from p in "DBO.SALESCARD"
                            select new SalesInvoice
                            {
                                ID = p.ID,
                                InvoiceNo = p.InvoiceNo,
                                DateTime = p.DateTime,
                                ContactName = p.CustomerCard.ContactName,
                                CompanyName = p.CustomerCard.CompanyName
                            }).ToList();
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use the table name? The whole point of an ORM like EF is to let you get away from the DB as much as possible.

Comment: you could use expression to define runtime what you want to select from, but like Oded said, whats the point of that

Comment: The DB Tables are created dynamically so I know their name.  They are not known at design time.  Is there a way to build EF during runtime? does it even make sense?

Comment: Your POCO classes should be the your tables and they should be set in your `DBContext`. In this case `entities.SalesCards` your entities variable should equal your context.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use EF just to map some query to your object

```
Db.Database.SqlQuery<SalesInvoice>("SELECT ID, InvoiceNo, DateTime, ContactName, CompanyName FROM dbo.[SALESCARD]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i am understanding what you want to do correctly but if i am this should be a easy solution to what you are trying to do.

```
  public List<SalesInvoice> GetSalesInvoices()
    {
       var _db = new yourDbContext();

    var query = _db.TableThatHasSalesInvoices;

    return query.ToList(); 
    }
```